# Standard name for rational Levi subgroups of rational parabolic groups

Tags: rt.representation-theory

I am looking for a standard name for the groups above. They appear in Harish-Chandra theory. It would be convenient to have a shorter name for them. I tried looking online but I did not find useful information.

Thank you.